# How to add a submenu entry to Eclipse Package Explorer context menu item using org.eclipse.ui.menus?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, popup, contextmenu, submenu

I am trying to add a submenu entry to an item from the context menu of the Eclipse Package Explorer.

The menu entry is already defined via org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus in another plugin, not in the one that I am working at. (That plugin is added to the dependencies list of my plugin). There are also items added in its submenu, but also using org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus, and I am trying to do this via org.eclipse.ui.menus.

To begin with, I did the following:

- I added org.eclipse.ui.commands and org.eclipse.ui.menus extensions.
- I defined a command , respectively a menuContribution like this:

[image]

This adds the item in any context menu... So I would have to replace "org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions" from the locationURI with the id of the submenu I want my item to appear in.

**My problem is: how to determine a correct locationURI?**
I used the menu spy (ALT+SHIFT+F2) and inspected the submenu I want to contribute to, and I received the following URI:

menu:YYY?after=ZZZ, where:

YYY is the id of the menu that is already defined and to which I want to add the submenu item
ZZZ is the id of the action from the submenu, that I clicked upon (using the spy)

I tryied the following, but the submenu item does not appear:

- menu:YYY[?after=additions]
- popup:YYY[?after=additions]

Please help :)

Comment: have you tried popup:YYYY?after=ZZZ ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, and it didn't help. But I have just managed to make it work. I had to define a new menu contribution and a menu having the same id and label as the menu already defined - YYY & YYY's label, like this: 
<menuContribution 
locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="YYY"
               label="YYYs_label">
         </menu>
</menuContribution>

With this, and replacing the locationURI with: "popup:YYY?after=additions" now it works. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it works.

Comment: ...and thanks a lot for your interest and for trying to help me :)

Comment: you are most welcome. I am glad you made it work. btw, you can add an answer yourself and accept it, I guess this is encouraged to make it easier for others to know the answer if they face the same problem

Answer (score 11):

I managed to make it work by defining a new menu contribution and a menu having the same id and label as the menu already defined. The final solution looks like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
     <menu
           id="YYY"
           label="%YYYs_label">
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:YYY?after=additions">
     <command
           commandId="example.MyCommandHandlerID"
           icon="icons/somePhoto.gif"
           label="MyLabel"
           style="push">
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Comment: This is the only workaround.  `org.eclipse.ui.menus` contributions are applied before any of the legacy action extensions, like `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` or `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`.

Comment: the URI for the **Package** Explorer's context menu is `popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?after=additions`