# Package Explorer URI eclipse plugin context menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, contextmenu

On the eclipse plugin that I am working on I want to add a context menu **"myAction"** on the **Package Explorer** view, just after **"Delete"** when you right click on a java class in the package explorer for example.

Right now I have a menuContribution, popup:

```
 <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.edit?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="plugin.myActionCommand"
               icon="icons/myAction.gif"
               style="push"
               tooltip="hello">
         </command>
 </menuContribution>
```

I found this LocationURI by doing (ALT+SHIFT+F2) on "Delete" as mentioned in this post : [How to add a submenu entry to Eclipse Package Explorer context menu item using org.eclipse.ui.menus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617898/how-to-add-a-submenu-entry-to-eclipse-package-explorer-context-menu-item-using-o)
But it does not work.

My questions are : Should I use **popup:** or **menu:** in my LocationURI? Which URI is it for Package Explorer view -> (right click) Delete? And does there is now a better way than this old SO post, that could make it work?

PS : I know you could say it's duplicated BUT I am wondering if the answer is not outdated, and he didn't clearly answer the orginal question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context menus are `popup:` menus.

The Package Explorer view context menu id is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer`

The group in the context menu containing 'Delete' is `group.edit`.

All the above confirmed by reading the Package Explorer source code (`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart`).

So this `menuContribution` adds after Delete:

```xml
<menuContribution
    allPopups="false"
    locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer?endof=group.edit">
```